# jquery manipulate a couple of links

Tags: jquery, replace, split, href

i have a couple of links i need to correct using some jquery. The links are formatted like this:

http://www.xyz.de/produkte/angebote/kategorie/angebote/produkte/singleview/produkt/oranier-wassertechnik-solar-pufferspeicher-set-2/

I want to split the href an get everything thats behind the last two slashes, while everything in front is being deleted.

My best shot was the following:

```
$('.tt-products-listhighlights a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr("href", function(index, old) {
        return old.replace("produkt/", "produkte/singleview/produkt/");
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will go with split but there may be a better way

```
$('.tt-products-listhighlights a').each(function() {

  var ary= $(this).attr("href").split("/");
  var lst=parseInt(ary.length)-2;

 ary[lst];//this is the last text

});
```